# Add button disabled (grayed) when trying to add new openconnect connection

Tags: gnome, network-manager, 17.10, openvpn

native NetworkManager openconnect (cisco anyconnect) connection master used to create a new connection and worked well in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. Lately I migrated to Ubuntu 17.10 and when I'm trying to create a new connection I can't click Add button because it is grayed:
[image]

I didn't used any CA cartificates before, i just typed username and password and it worked like a charm. I installed all packages needed, like network-manager-openvpn-gnome

Comment: I have the exact same problem here. :(

Comment: @Taschetto I found solution, but my answer was deleted. Actually, if you need to add new openconnnect (cisco anyconnect) vpn connection, you should install `network-manager-openconnect` with `network-manager-openconnect-gnome` package. Then use native NW manager to create new openconnect connection. OpenVPN is not a option for this.